# how to pass all the xml files located in one folder to libxml for parsing

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, libxml2

I have written the C code and have used libxml to parse the xml file by providing its absolute file , now my requirement is to pass only the folder name and to pick all the xm files one by one and parse them completely. is there any specific method through which libxml takes all the files from the folder or can we mention files sperated by comma or any other delimiter in the configuration file through which libxml picks the path of the file to parse.

Comment: I think windows uses ';' in the PATH environment variable and gets away with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at FindFirstFile and FindNextFile, since you're on Windows.